# A tiny Java library for generating Gray codes

Tags: java, algorithm, unit-testing, library

This library is for generating Gray codes. A Gray code over \$n\$ bits is a list of \$2^n\$ different \$n\$-bit strings subject to the following constraint: two adjacent bit string differ in only one position. For example, the Gray code over four bits is

`0000
0001
0011
0010
0110
0111
0101
0100
1100
1101
1111
1110
1010
1011
1001
1000`

Without further ado, let's proceed to code.

**GrayCode.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graycode;

import java.util.BitSet;

/**
 * This class holds the Gray code.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jan 4, 2018)
 */
public final class GrayCode {

    private final BitSet[] code;
    private final int bits;

    GrayCode(BitSet[] code, int bits) {
        this.code = code;
        this.bits = bits;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        if (getNumberOfBits() == 0) {
            return code.length == 0;
        }

        int rowLength = getNumberOfBits();
        BitSet previousRow = getRow(0);

        for (int row = 1; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
            BitSet currentRow = getRow(row);

            if (getDifferenceCounts(previousRow, currentRow) != 1) {
                return false;
            }

            previousRow = currentRow;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int getNumberOfBits() {
        return bits;
    }

    public int getNumberOfRows() {
        return this.code.length;
    }

    public BitSet getRow(int index) {
        BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(getNumberOfBits());

        for (int i = 0; i < bits; ++i) {
            bitSet.set(i, code[index].get(i));
        }

        return bitSet;
    }

    public boolean readBit(int row, int column) {
        return code[row].get(column);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String rowSeparator = "";

        for (int row = 0; row < code.length; ++row) {
            stringBuilder.append(rowSeparator);
            rowSeparator = "\n";
            rowToBitString(stringBuilder, code[row]);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private void rowToBitString(StringBuilder stringBuilder, BitSet bitSet) {
        for (int i = 0; i != bits; ++i) {
            stringBuilder.append(bitSet.get(i) ? '1' : '0');
        }
    }

    private int getDifferenceCounts(BitSet row1, BitSet row2) {
        int differenceCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bits; ++i) {
            if (row1.get(i) != row2.get(i)) {
                differenceCount++;

                if (differenceCount == 2) {
                    return differenceCount;
                }
            }
        }

        return differenceCount;
    }
}
```

**GrayCodeGenerator.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graycode;

import java.util.BitSet;

/**
 * This class provides a method for generating Gray code over particular number
 * of bits.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jan 4, 2018)
 */
public class GrayCodeGenerator {

    public static GrayCode generate(int bits) {
        checkBits(bits);

        if (bits == 0) {
            return new GrayCode(new BitSet[0], 0);
        }

        BitSet[] bitSetArray = new BitSet[getNumberOfBitStrings(bits)];

        for (int i = 0; i != bitSetArray.length; ++i) {
            bitSetArray[i] = new BitSet(bits);
        }

        bitSetArray[1].set(bits - 1);

        for (int bitIndex = bits - 1, columnHeight = 2, width = 1;
                bitIndex > 0;
                bitIndex--, columnHeight <<= 1, ++width) {
            // Mirror down:
            for (int row1 = columnHeight,
                     row2 = columnHeight - 1;
                    row1 < (columnHeight << 1); 
                    row1++,
                    row2--) {
                for (int w = bits - 1; w > bitIndex - 1; w--) {
                    bitSetArray[row1].set(w, bitSetArray[row2].get(w));
                }
            }

            // Fill the prefix bits:
            for (int row = columnHeight; row < (columnHeight << 1); ++row) {
                bitSetArray[row].set(bitIndex - 1);
            }
        }

        return new GrayCode(bitSetArray, bits);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of rows in the Gray code over {@code bits} bits.
     * 
     * @param bits the number of bits.
     * @return the number of rows in the resulting Gray code.
     */
    private static int getNumberOfBitStrings(int bits) {
        return 1 << bits;
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the number of bits is not negative.
     * 
     * @param bits the number of bits to check.
     */
    private static void checkBits(int bits) {
        if (bits < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Negative number of bits requested: " + bits);
        }
    }
}
```

**GrayCodeDemo.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graycode;

/**
 * This class implements a sample Gray code demonstration.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jan 4, 2018)
 */
public final class GrayCodeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GrayCode grayCode = GrayCodeGenerator.generate(4);
        System.out.println(grayCode);
        System.out.println("Valid Gray code: " + grayCode.isValid());
    }
}
```

**GrayCodeTest.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graycode;

import java.util.BitSet;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class GrayCodeTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        GrayCode grayCode = GrayCodeGenerator.generate(2);
        assertEquals(4, grayCode.getNumberOfRows());
        assertEquals(2, grayCode.getNumberOfBits());
        System.out.println(grayCode);
        assertTrue(grayCode.isValid());

        // Check first column:
        assertFalse(grayCode.readBit(0, 0));
        assertFalse(grayCode.readBit(1, 0));
        assertTrue(grayCode.readBit(2, 0));
        assertTrue(grayCode.readBit(3, 0));

        // Check second column:
        assertFalse(grayCode.readBit(0, 1));
        assertTrue(grayCode.readBit(1, 1));
        assertTrue(grayCode.readBit(2, 1));
        assertFalse(grayCode.readBit(3, 1));

        BitSet row1 = grayCode.getRow(1);
        assertFalse(row1.get(0));
        assertTrue(row1.get(1));
    }

    @Test
    public void bruteForceTest() {
        for (int bits = 0; bits < 12; bits++) {
            assertTrue(GrayCodeGenerator.generate(bits).isValid());
        }
    }
}
```

## Critique request

Please tell me anything that comes to mind. I am most interested in comments regarding the API design.

Comment: (Was about to dismiss this (because no purpose stated or leaping at me), but, wait: this isn't *reflected binary*, only?)

Comment: @greybeard Added some more content to the critique request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a bit missing, is the logic / proof / explanation. And it is generative, creating a sequence.

Hence one could look at an immediate mapping function:

```
static int grayCode(int n) {
    assert n >= 0;
    if (n == 0) {
       return 0;
    }
    int high = Integer.highestOneBit(n);
    int lows = n & ~high; // Or n - high
    return high | grayCode(high - 1 - lows); // Reverse order backwards
}
```

- Proof can be done by induction because of the recursion.
- The recursion can be resolved a bit. (Also generative with a non-tail recursion.)
- An explanation is simple too:

> Having a valid sequence of 0 .. 2<sup>k</sup> - 1, the following 2<sup>k</sup> numbers can be retrieved by reversing the list and adding a bit 1 in front: every step also flips one single bit.

*I did not want to spoil this nice usage of BitSet, but Gray Codes seem useful, like de-Bruijn sequences.*

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would have put the generator code (and helper functions) within the `GrayCode` class, not within its own class. A key point here is that there is not initialiser for the `GrayCodeGenerator` class.
You can then use this to see if the gray code has been set - useful for avoiding programming errors where the future code declares a `GrayCode` but does not generate with it.
You could also use this for a new constructor where only a number of bits is passed, and the `GrayCode` class then automatically generates the `BitSet`. Yes, you could also do this with the current code, but having the generator inside the `GrayCode` class will make it neater.

Answer (score 2):

As interface design is pivotal in type design, I'm happy to start there -
let me refer to [`java.util.BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). In no uncertain terms, the documentation summarises in just two sentences what `BitSet` is about: element access and
bulk boolean operations (see [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for something irritatingly similar)
(leaving out summaries ([`cardinality()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#cardinality--) and [`intersects​(BitSet other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#intersects-java.util.BitSet-)) and paraphernalia).

I like that it is possible to have non-*reflected binary* codes - assuming a
`GrayCode(int nBits, long ... codes)`: `new GrayCode(3, 0, 1, 3, 7, 6, 4)`.
I second [AJD](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/184309/93149) in preferring a constructor with a single `int` parameter as an alternative to a separate generator class for [*reflected binary*](https://en.mwikipedia.org/wiki/Gray-code#Motivation) Gray codes.
With that change, the whole API collapses to `public boolean GrayCode.isValid()` - which in itself is weird:
Objects should be constructed in a valid state and never get invalid if that can be helped.
(Another hint about the API is the lack of documentation - compare to `BitSet`.)

Then, there is implementation:

- `getRow()` could just `return (BitSet) code[index].clone();`
- ```
  int getDifferenceCount(BitSet row1, BitSet row2) {
      BitSet bits = (BitSet) row1.clone();
      bits.xor(row2);
      return bits.cardinality();
  }
  ```

`isValid()` needs to initialise `BitSet previousRow = getRow(getNumberOfRows()-1);` and start from 0 to check every transition - but even that is just one necessary condition where a second comes to mind: no code may repeat. (I don't know better that to sort with a "throwing comparator".)